# Setting error on form control field based on the value of another field

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have an edit user dialog box where I'm allowing the user to edit the user attributes. For editing the password, I need the user to enter the new password & confirm it. The confirm password field should be mandatory only if the password field has some value as the user can edit other values apart from the password too. I'm trying to do this through a custom validator but am unable to do so. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Here is my form group:

```
this.userForm = new FormGroup({
        username: new FormControl(this.data.user.username, [Validators.required]),
        firstName: new FormControl(this.data.user.firstName, [Validators.required]),
        email: new FormControl(this.data.user.email, [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
        password: new FormControl('', []),
        passwordAgain: new FormControl('', [isEmpty('password') ]),
      });
```

My custom validator:

```
export function isEmpty(matchingControlName: string): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
    if (!control.parent) {
      return null;
    }

    const dest = control.parent.controls[matchingControlName];

    // // set error if validation fails
    if (control.value==='' && dest.value!='') {
      return { empty: true };
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: I think the issue here is that validators only trigger when something in their own control changes. But passWordAgain is never changed. The trick in solving this (usually) is to make a group validator for passwords. So something like passwordGroup: new FormGroup({pass: new FormControl(), passAgain: new Formcontrol}, [groupValidator]) (pseudo code)

Comment: As you correctly said, passwordAgain is not touched so the validator is not triggered. I am now adding the validator to the password control & a the adding validators to passwordAgain there based on the valid condition. With this approach I'm able to get it working as expected. Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can add another condition in your your custom validator

```
if (control.value==='' && dest.value!='') {
  return { empty: true };
} else {
  return control.value!=dest.value?{notMatch:true}:null;
}
```

Yes a custom validator can return different errors -you check `*ngIf="userForm.get('passwordAgain').errors?.empty"` and `*ngIf="userForm.get('passwordAgain').errors?.notMatch"`

But the main problem is that Angular only check the validator of a control if you change the control. For this you can take two approach

1.- in submit makes an updateValueAndValidity over the control passwordAgain before send the value

```
 submit(userForm:FormGroup){
    //updateValue and validity the "passwordAgain"
    userForm.get('passwordAgain').updateValueAndValidity();

    //mark all controls as touched
    userForm.markAllAsTouched()
    if (userForm.valid)
    {
      .....your code...
    }
  }
```

2.-After create the form subscribe to password valueChange to updateValueAndValidity the paswwrodAgain

```
this.userForm.get('password').valueChanges.subscribe(_=>{
  this.userForm.get('passwordAgain').updateValueAndValidity()
})
```

**Update** After see the MikOne's comment there are another option that is make the validator over the formGroup -this makes any change in any input execute the validator-